# stddev pct contrib / rollapply / performanceanalytics / R / subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, xts, zoo, rollapply, performanceanalytics

I am trying to construct rolling risk contributions by each security using the PerformanceAnalytics package. Once I can get past this error I would like to plot the results over time. I keep receiving the error that the subscript is out of bounds and i'm not sure where to start in terms of resolving it. This is the error specifically:

```
Error in `[.xts`(x, i, which.i = TRUE) : subscript out of bounds
```

Not very experienced with R. Thank you for any guidance! Here is the code.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

symbols <- c("SPY","EEM","BND","BIL")

prices <- 
  getSymbols(symbols, src = 'yahoo', from = "2016-01-01", 
             auto.assign = TRUE, warnings = FALSE) %>% 
  map(~Cl(get(.))) %>% 
  reduce(merge) %>%
  `colnames<-`(symbols)

portfolioComponentReturns <- na.omit(Return.calculate(prices, method = "log"))

w = c(.25,.25,.25,.25)

rollingvolpct <- na.omit(rollapply(portfolioComponentReturns,

                                   width=252,
                                   FUN = function(Z)
                                   {
                                     t = StdDev(portfolioComponentReturns,weights = w, portfolio_method = "components", data = as.data.frame(Z), na.rm=T);
                                     return(t$pct_contrib)
                                   },
                                   by.column=FALSE, align="right"))
```

Comment: Could you please add the other required packages for this code to run?  It looks like maybe `quantmod`, `purrr`, `magrittr` to name a few may be needed.